# .name wont capitalise?

Tags: vba, capitalize

trying to create a code that takes any set of data, no matter how long and wide, and creates individual charts for each column of data. Currently my .Name = ActiveSheet.Name wont capitalise the name and is bugging out.

ideally want to get the code to a state where it doesnt matter what sheet the data is in and where the data starts within the sheet.

full code below, very open to improvements and very much appreciated!

```
Sub AddCharts3()


    Dim i As Integer 'rows
    Dim j As Integer 'columns
    Dim Col As Integer

    i = Cells(Rows.count, 2).End(xlUp).Row
    Col = Cells(5, Columns.count).End(xlToLeft).Column


    For j = 3 To Col
        With Sheets("CMT Data").Shapes.AddChart.Chart
        .ChartType = xlColumnClustered
        .SeriesCollection.NewSeries
            With .SeriesCollection(1)
           .name = "=" & ActiveSheet.name & "!" & _
           Cells(5, j).Address
           .XValues = "=" & ActiveSheet.name & "!" & _
           Range(Cells(6, 2), Cells(i, 2)).Address
           .Values = "=" & ActiveSheet.name & "!" & _
           Range(Cells(6, j), Cells(i, j)).Address
           End With
       .Location xlLocationAsObject, name:="ChartPack"
       .HasLegend = False
       Sheets("Data").Select
    
      End With
   Next j

    Dim shp As Shape
    Dim Cnt As Long
    Dim dTop As Double
    Dim dLeft As Double
    Dim dHeight As Double
    Dim dWidth As Double
    Dim start As Double

    Const ColCnt As Long = 5

    Cnt = 1

   Sheets("ChartPack").Select
    ActiveSheet.ChartObjects.Select

    For Each shp In Selection.ShapeRange
        With shp
           If Cnt = 1 Then
               .Top = Range("B5").Top
               .Left = Range("B5").Left
               start = .Left
        Else
            If Cnt Mod ColCnt = 1 Then
                .Top = dTop + dHeight
                .Left = start
            Else
                .Top = dTop
                .Left = dLeft + dWidth
            End If
        End If
        
        dTop = .Top
        dLeft = .Left
        dHeight = .Height
        dWidth = .Width
        
     End With
    
    Cnt = Cnt + 1
    
Next shp


End Sub
```

Comment: Write `Dim Name`, then remove it.